# On mouseover using Javascript I have a separate div changing colour but I need to reset the function after use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is a link to the code.

I need to be able to hover back and forth from "red" and "blk" with the functions changing the colour back and forth also.  I believe it needs to be reset somehow?

http://jsfiddle.net/kAMG7/

```
$('#red').on('mouseover', function() {
$('#blue1').addClass("green");
});
$('#blk').on('mouseover', function() {
$('#blue1').addClass("black");
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use css :hover

Comment: `green` and `black` are not the best class names. Some refactoring or redesigning could lead to css like `.green { color: red; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$('#red').on('mouseover', function() {
$('#blue1').addClass("green");
$('#blue1').removeClass("black");
});
$('#blk').on('mouseover', function() {
$('#blue1').addClass("black");
$('#blue1').removeClass("green");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#red').mouseover(function() {
$('#blue1').addClass("green");
});
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#red').mouseout(function() {
$('#blue1').removeClass("green");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#red").hover(
  function() {
    $("#blue1").addClass("green");
  },
  function() {
    $('#blue1').removeClass("green");
  }
);

$("#blk").hover(
  function() {
    $("#blue1").addClass("black");
  },
  function() {
    $('#blue1').removeClass("black");
  }
);
```